# How to detect Smart Phones using Plugin.BLE in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello Everyone,
Currently i'm facing issue in Scanning **mobile devices(OnePlus and OPPO)** using Plugin.BLE in Xamarin.Forms. Able to detect devices like Speakers and Smart Watches using plugin. Is there any alternate way to scan smartphones which advertise some data? Added all required permissions and features.Kindly help me out!!

Thanks in Advance.